# Kivy change color of the scrollbar in a spinner

Tags: colors, scrollbar, spinner, kivy

I have a Spinner widget with a list of items higher than my screen, so a scroll bar appears.

I want to know if i can change the color of this scroll bar, or how to remove it if not.

I tried to change it with bar_color but no effect in the Spinner..

Answer (score 1):

`Spinner` itself doesn't have any `bar_color`. `Spinner` create a `Dropdown` which inherit of a `ScrollView`. What you have to do is to customize the `Dropdown` class:

```
from functools import partial
ColoredDropdown = partial(Dropdown, bar_color=(1, 0, 0, 1))

# and then
spinner = Spinner(dropdown_cls=ColoredDropdown)
```